# How to prove that $\gcd(2n+3, 3n+1)$ divides $7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

How can I start proving that gcd(2n+3, 3n+1) | 7?

EDIT: It is $\gcd(2n+3, 3n+1)$ divides $7$. My bad. Thanks paw88789.

Comment: Do you know $gcd(a,b+ac)=gcd(a,b)$?

Comment: Hint: Find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a(2n+3)-b(3n+1)$ has no $n$ in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\gcd(2n+3, 3n+1) = \gcd(n-2, 3n+1) = \gcd(n-2, 7) \mid  7$$

Answer (score 4):

As to the problem $gcd(2n+3,3n+1)|7$ we shall use the euclidean algorithm.

So $3n+1=2n+3+(n-2)$

$(2n+3)=2(n-2)+7$

So a divisor of $3n+1$ and $2n+3$ must divide $7$

Answer (score 1):

As $(a,b)$ must divide $ax+by$  for integers $x,y$

$(2n+3,3n+1)$ must divide $3(2n+3)-2(3n+1)=7$

The idea in such problems is to eliminate the variable $(n)$

Comment: @user2803048, How about this?

Answer (score 0):

By Euclid theorem
GCD(2n+3,3n+1)=a(2n+3)+b(3n+1)
=>GCD(2n+3,3n+1)=n(2a+3b)+(3a+b)----------eqn1

To find Gcd n coefficient equate to zero.
2a+3b=0
=>a/b=-3/2

Take minimum values for a and b
a=3 and b=-2
Substitute in eqn1
GCD(2n+3,3n+1)=n(0)+(3*3-2)
GCD(2n+3,3n+1)=7
Hence proved.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).